# FFMPEG Interpolated Video | First frame frozen without any interpolation to the second one

Tags: powershell, ffmpeg, interpolation, generative-adversarial-network

I've a small issue when generating interpolated videos from a short image sequence for a VQGAN+Clip Art Porject

The problem i've is just that the first frame stucks for a moment, then it jumps to the second one, the second one is also stuck for a moment but then it starts and works nicely. My biggest problem with it is the harsh transition from 1st to 2nd frame, the 2nd frame "start delay" is not that big an issue to me, but woul also be nice to get rid of for

Thats my command for generating the Video from an image sequence

```
ffmpeg -framerate 1 -i Upscaled\%d_out.png -vcodec h264_nvenc -pix_fmt yuv420p -strict -2 -vf minterpolate="mi_mode=mci:me=hexbs:me_mode=bidir:mc_mode=aobmc:vsbmc=1:mb_size=8:search_param=32:fps=30" InterpolatedVideo.mp4
```

You can see the result [>> HERE <<](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VMRkK.jpg)

Now my question is if thats fixable by editing the command & if so, how?
I'd like to keep the first frame, but having it interpolate to the second frame.

I want to avoid to manually cut it afterwards, as i'd need to know the time to cut etc.

Thanks for any help in advance

Greetings from Vienna

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so what the problem was is the scene change detection aka. the scd parameter of the interpolation instruction. It's set to fdiff(frame difference) by default. Setting it to none with scd=none in the interpolation instruction gets rid of it

I also had to copy the 1st frame TWICE at the end to create a smooth loop. With only one, it entirely missed the last(copied first frame). I now copied it once morre at the end and it works now super smoothly. I guess the very last frame could be anything, as it misses it anyway